# Ignore case android studio 3 code completion

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0, code-completion

Currently code completion is case sensitive so when i type names, it doesn't show me suggestions. how do i make it ignore case?

as an example when i type `Sta` or `sta` it should suggest `startActivity`.

I could not find it in the settings, I'm lazy to be honest.

PS. I have C# writing habits and this becomes annoying over time.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General | Code completion | Match Case

Answer (score 32):

from `File` > `Settings` uncheck `Mactch case` as illustrated in this image

[image]